# How could the stars be going out in the alternate universe?

Tags: plot-explanation, doctor-who

In **Turn Left** we see what the world would be like if Donna never met the Doctor and he perished beating the Racnoss.

In this timeline, we cryptically see Rose all over the place using the companions to prevent the other earthly disasters before the final disaster comes in the blotting out of the stars.  Which Rose explains is happening to all the other parallel universes.

We learn by the end of the season this was caused by the Dalek's Crucible, using Davros' Reality Bomb.

However, in order for the Crucible to work in the first place, the Earth must be present in the "Planetary engine" alignment.  During Donna's alternate reality the Earth wasn't taken for this purpose and merely witnessed as the end came about, before Donna shattered that reality and went back to the true reality.

The question then becomes, how could the Dalek's accomplish this in this reality if the Earth is still in place?

Comment: Timey-wimey, wibbly... oh, I just can't bring myself to finish...

Comment: Its the stuff isn't it?

Comment: Hard question... now i have to think. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the episode turn left Donna creates two parallel universes.

> 1 Where the doctor never meets Donna and where he dies. and therefore cannot prevent the Daleks stealing the earth and using the reality bomb.
>
> And another universe where the earth is never stolen, but where the blast of the reality bomb (from the first universe) still reaches them and destroys the stars.

The Dalek only needed one earth to exterminate everything.

Hope it makes sense.